# How to clone image and data for VM on Azure?

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machines, azure, image

I'm trying to find a way to clone the image of one VM on Azure. I knew some information about 'sysprep' and Linux system, but those require delete the previous VM.
In my case, I don't want to delete the previous VM because I want to keep it working as usual. it's just like copy and paste one file, file name is different but it has the same content. There are no collisions between the previous VM and the new VM. Both VM can work individually.

Any help would be grateful.
Thank You.

Comment: There are many ways to clone VMs, then you can sysprep either onprem or in the azure cloud.

Answer (score 3):

This is a loaded question. There are two ways to go about what you want.

1. Sysprep and image - This means creating a generalized version of the OS and then using it to create a bunch of new VMs. This is advantageous when you want the ability to clone (but grant new usernames and password, computer names, etc to) the VMs. This also allows the VMs to co-exist in the same network.
2. Capturing a VM Image - This allows the above as well as an additional option to capture a running VM and make copies of it. Note that in this case, the copies are exact replicas of the original VM down to the contents of the disk and the computer names, usernames and passwords. Same computer names may make it difficult for the clones to co-exist in the same network.

Both approaches require you to create an image (compare it to clicking on the copy button) and then using that image to create a new VM (compare to clicking paste).

Comment: Hello, there is one question I want to ask. I read some articles about sysrep on Azure, it says the previous VM will be deleted when image is captured. Did I miss some points?

Comment: The previous VM is deleted only if the VM you are capturing is Stopped (generalized case). If you capture a running VM (specialized case), it won't be deleted.

See this http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/04/14/vm-image-blog-post/ 

(If the OS is specialized, the virtual machine can be captured while it is running or shut down.  The captured virtual machine remains untouched.)